# delete old image while updating the field

Tags: laravel

I am doing CRUD operations for images. when I am doing the update operation image gets updated but the old image doesn't delete. The following code updates only the file name in the database but I need to remove the old image from the destination folder too while updating else the folder size will become too large. Any ideas would be great. Here my code.

```
<input type="file" name="profileimage"  value="{{ isset($editabout) ? $editabout->profileimage : '' }}" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
```

Here is my controller

```
public function update(updateAboutusProfile $request, AboutUs $about)
{
    $data=$request->only(['profiletext']);

    if($request->hasFile('profileimage')){
        $profileimage = $request->profileimage->store('aboutus', 'public');
        $oldimage = $about->profileimage;

        Storage::delete($oldimage);
        $data['profileimage'] = $profileimage;
    }

    $about->update($data);
    toastr()->success('Profile updated successfully');

    return redirect(route('about.index'));
    //
}
```

What can be the error I need to resolve,
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the disk you used to store the file

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete($oldimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete image from your server, you have to reference location of file in directory server, means you could not reference by url link to delete it.

**Laravel file is locate in `public folder`.**

```
Example: your files are located in public/images


$image_path = "/images/filename.ext";  // Value is not URL but directory file path    
if(File::exists($image_path)) {
     File::delete($image_path);                                                  
   }
```

**Enjoy ;)**

Answer (score 0):

You should save the path of the file to the database and then simply remove it using `\Storage::delete()` facade.

### Store image using hash name

```
if($request->hasFile('profileimage')){
    $store_path = 'aboutus';
    $profileimage = $request->profileimage->store($store_path,'public');
    $oldimage = $about->profileimage;

    $file_address = $store_path.'/'.$request->profileimage->hashName();
    \Storage::disk('public')->delete($oldimage);
    $data['profileimage'] = $file_address;
}
```

### Store image using original name

```
if($request->hasFile('profileimage')){
    $store_path = 'aboutus';
    $profileimage = $request->profileimage->storeAs($store_path, $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(),'public');
    $oldimage = $about->profileimage;

    $file_address = $store_path.'/'.$request->profileimage->getClientOriginalName();
    \Storage::disk('public')->delete($oldimage);
    $data['profileimage'] = $file_address;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old image while updating

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // other updates
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            //delete old image if exist
            if (File::exists(public_path($oldImage))) {
                File::delete(public_path(oldImage));
            }
            //new image process
        }
    }
```